# Integration testing - mimic expected delays

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, rhino-mocks

**In summary**:

How do I create "integration" tests that mimic expected delays from external systems?

**In detail**:

I have an application "Main" that communicates with multiple external systems (via web services) which I'll call "Partners".

I am disinterested in the inner workings of the Partners, but I need to fully test Main.

For Main I currently have:

- Unit Tests for each individual testable block [so test every public method on every class at every "level" (n-tier) and stub every dependency]
- Integration tests that test from the top-down (so test all public methods on the Presentation tier and stub only these partner web services)

What I would also like is to create some integration tests to ensure that the code in MAIN delivers the correct performance.

What is "correct performance"?  Well, the Product Manager can say "all Views must return data within 2 seconds".  I know that (on average) a call to a partner takes (say) 1.5 seconds so I could write my Integration test with a stop watch that passes if the Main code completed in 0.5 seconds (2 - 1.5).  However, in a discussion with a colleague it was suggested that the Stub for the partner should include the 1.5 second expected delay, and so my test should be that the Main code plus stub for partner should complete within the 2 seconds as specified by PM.

QUs:

1. What is the suggested behaviour?
2. If as suggested, how is this achieved using Rino Mocks for stubbing?

Thanks everyone

Griff

Comment: When come to asserting run times, remember that they are depending on the machine running them - A build server may present better performance than a developer machine (or vice versa).

Comment: That's a very good point and one that makes me wonder whether this is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

"all Views must return data within 2 seconds" makes no sense. when limiting the response time, you should also consider the load. when there will be 1 request per 10 second then your views may return in 2 seconds. but when there will be 10k request per second then your response time will be "slightly" longer. better performance requirement would be "x% of responses will take not more then y seconds when load is below z requests per seconds" or something similar.

unit testing delays also makes no sense. you should run full scale performance tests. choose one of the existing tools, prepare a few client nodes (controlled with that tool), run recorded/scripted clients' requests against your tested server and check what are the response times, cpu and memory usage. then add one or mode nodes to your system and check how the system is scaling